# Rails: Cannot create new documents with MongoMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongomapper

I have been using MongoMapper with Rails 5.2.
Creating model:

```
class Item
    include MongoMapper::Document
    key :title, String
    key :description, String
end
```

In the MongoDB, I inserted the document

```
{
    "title": "demo",
    "description": "this is the demo item"
}
```

Using Rails console to test this model

```
Item.where({:title => "demo"}).first
```

It shows the result is the document above.
But when I create a new document with:

```
item = Item.create({:title => "demo2", :description => "the demo2"})
```

An error in the console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):3
    1: from (eval):9:in `title='
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass)
```

I tried with the method `new`

```
item = Item.new
```

The console shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):4
    1: from (irb):4:in `new'
NoMethodError (undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongomapper is not compatible with rails 5.2

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer. Maybe suggest other solution or give recommendation how to solve the problem of OP?